# Is it possible to link a font from a CDN and use it in an SSRS report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to use a free font from google without having to fully install it on my machine (customer request, wont budge). Is there any way to use the link the font from a CDN to be used within the report?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the report to render with the font, it has to be installed on the server where it's running. So on your machine for development and also on whatever server it will be deployed to.